# Erlang EDTS compile options

Tags: emacs, erlang, rebar

When using [EDTS](https://github.com/tjarvstrand/edts) erlang **`emacs`** IDE, it doesn't seem to me that there is much integration with rebar, so I am wondering how to specify compile options so that I can add `debug_info` and `{parse_transform, lager_transform}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDTS kinda works on `.beams`, and with this it should be able to compile with exactly the same options. Let me explain.

EDTS works with notion of project (it's accualy `xref` server, lets assume that those are more or less the same).  When you open one source file, he adds it to the "project list", and than he adds all other modules he can find.  What is important here, is fact that he is doing it based on `.beam` files.  It have two major significance.

First, if you modules aren't compiled he will think that you make calls to undefined functions (with exception of files that you actually opened in your editor, of course).

Second is fact, that if he can find once compiled binary, he can read and reuse compile flags from it.  Of course all new files created in `emacs` won't have `.beam` with those options, so they will be compiled with default ones.

So, if you have any issues with the way your files are compiled/modules you can reference just recompile them from command line

```
$ ./rebar clean compile
```

and reinitialize EDTS with `M-x edts-project-node-refresh` or `M-x edts-project-node-init`